# Spark Streaming: foreachRDD update my mongo RDD

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to create a **new** mongodb RDD each time I enter inside `foreachRDD`. However I have serialization issues:

```
 mydstream  
   .foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val mongoClient = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
      val db = mongoClient(mongoDatabase)
      val coll = db(mongoCollection)
      // ssc is my StreamingContext
      val modelsRDDRaw = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(coll.find().toList) })
```

This will give me an error:

```
object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, value: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@31133b6e)
```

Any idea?

Comment: `SparkContext` is not serializable, so you cannot use inside any transformation or action methods, you have to use only in driver class.

Comment: are there any specific reason why you are converting list to rdd inside foreachRDD method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try to use [rdd.context](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) that returns either a SparkContext or a SparkStreamingContext (if rdd is a DStream).

```
mydstream foreachRDD { rdd => {
      val mongoClient = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
      val db = mongoClient(mongoDatabase)
      val coll = db(mongoCollection)
      val modelsRDDRaw = rdd.context.parallelize(coll.find().toList) })
```

Actually, it seems that RDD has also a `.sparkContext` method. I honestly don't know the difference, maybe they are aliases (?).

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding you have to add if you have a "not serializable" object, you need to pass it through `foreachPartition` so you can make a connection to database on each node before running your processing.

```
mydstream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
        rdd.foreachPartition{
          val mongoClient = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
          val db = mongoClient(mongoDatabase)
          val coll = db(mongoCollection)
          // ssc is my StreamingContext
          val modelsRDDRaw = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(coll.find().toList) }})
```

Comment: You can try create your ssc inside the foreachRDD before rdd.foreachPartition  `val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointdirectory, functionToCreateContext _)`